# How to clear / refresh the cache in EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'm using following settings in persistence.xml (I use Eclipselink 2.6.4) from my web application:

```
<properties> 
    <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />        
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.query-results" value="true" /> 
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.index-foreign-keys" value="true" />
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF" />        
    <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />        
    <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />        
    <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.persist-on-commit" value="false" />
</properties>
```

I'm using the `@Cacheable(false)` annotation to prevent some entities from being cached. 
 
The `@Cache` annotation doesn't work any more in version 2.6.4. 
 
My question is, is there a possibility to clear the cache globally? Let say every 3 hours? 
Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't the cache annotation work?  For invalidating the cache, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Expiration and https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/cache006.htm

Comment: The reason why the annotation doens't work is related to my IDE (netbeans). Importing the package `javax.persistence.Cache` I got an incompatible type error. I have to import the right package (org.eclipse.persistence.annotations). Anyway, the cache annotation is not the solution I am looking for. I need a global one. Is there any? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by global - invalidation only applies to the shared cache, at the EMF level.  If you have more than one application running, you can look into cache coordination, which would allow each application to listen for events.  See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/cache010.htm

Comment: I understand, so I have to change every entity or better have them all extending a superclass where I define the cache strategy which will be inherited. The document is very interesting. I'll need some time to dive in. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2):

First level cache is enabled by default and you can not disable it. i.e. no settings in your persistence.xml file will disable first level cache.

You can only clear out all the entity manager objects by calling

```
entityManager.clear()
```

this will make subsequent queries go to the database (the first time) and then objects are again stored in the cache

In your case you would need to store your entitymanager objects in a register somewhere and have a loop through it every 3 hours to call the clear() function.

You can force each query to go to the database directly by calling

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear Eclipselink's second level cache by accessing the `Cache` object in the `EntityManagerFactory`:

```java
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```